# set my UWP app as system default music player

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I have developed a UWP music player [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer).

My question is, how can I allow users to set my app as the default music player, so that when I click on a music file, my app is launched to play the music?

---Update---

Now I have learned how to register the file extension of music files. But I am still wondering how can my app display the `MainPage` when launching from a file? I copied code from the `OnLauched` event but it doesn't work.

Link to my [App.xaml.cs](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/App.xaml.cs)

```
    protected override async void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnFileActivated(args);
        MediaHelper.SetMusicAndPlay(await Music.GetMusicAsync(args.Files[0].Path));
    }
```

Comment: The user should be able to choose that if you register for the extensions like `.mp3` etc.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT How can I register those extensions?

Comment: See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/ELEMENT-FILETYPEASSOCIATION)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thank you! I have a question about the File Activation mentioned in the document. It uses `WinJS.Application.addEventListener("activated", onActivatedHandler, false);` for registry but I am not able to use this for my UWP as that code seems only working on Win 8.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT by providing suggestion that is not an answer you have just made OP remove my 15 points on the correct answer. So please confirm that it is impossible to make automatic association - the solution you have provided will just work with "Open with..." menu, but not as the default app without any user intervention.

Comment: @IvanIčin you say "...without any user intervention" -- I addressed that in my first comment ("The user should be able to choose..."). You are correct that there's no way to do it automatically. Seaky, are you using a WWA? I don't think the latest VS even supports WWA anymore.

Comment: @IvanIčin Sorry for any confusions. What I mean is that user is able to select my app to be the default player, and user a music file to launch my app.

Answer (score 0):

The UWP framework doesn't offer this capability.

As this requires registry changes you can't do it even if you create a package that contains your UWP app and Win32 extension as it would have access only to the 'virtual' and not the real registry.

This is something that most people hate and shouldn't be done anyway even if it is technically possible.